# jquery file upload have error cross origin request blocked when request to web api cors

Tags: jquery-file-upload

although i assigned for controller as

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

or

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
```

or

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:54189", headers: "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token", methods: "*")]
```

for client side, i assigned for ajax request as below, it doesn't work. The browser occur "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at `http://localhost:54189/portfolio/upload/`. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS." for "moving the resouce to the same domain", what does it's mean ?

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
url: "http://localhost:54189/portfolio/upload/",
    multiple: true,
    type: "Post",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
crossDomain: true,
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    crossDomain: true,
    add: function (e, data) {
           data.submit();
   }
```

})

Please, share with me if you know something, thanks.